# Flutter: SearchBar hint text with internationalization

Tags: flutter, internationalization, searchbar, appbar

I want to have a search bar placed in the app bar. So I declared the Appbar giving it a TextField as title, with a controller on which I put a listener:

```
class _SearchView extends State<SearchView> {

      TextField appBarTitle;
      final TextEditingController _filterController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
   buildAppBarTitle();
    super.initState();
  }

      TextField buildAppBarTitle() {
        return appBarTitle = new TextField(
            controller: _filterController,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: AppLocalization.of(context).search
            )
        );
      }


    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(title: appBarTitle,),
    }
 }
```

The problem is: `hintText: AppLocalization.of(context).search`. Since is outside the Widget build, it doesn't have a context. How can I set this hint text?

Comment: Did you try sending context from "build" method to "buildAppBarTitle" method as parameter?

Comment: you mean to do something like:
TextField buildAppBarTitle(BuildContrext context){
return appBarTitle....
}

and then in the build:
appBar: AppBar(title:buildAppBarTitle(context))
?

Comment: Yeap, like that.

Comment: it breaks: stack overflow

Comment: Is it full code? Where do you assign buildAppBarTitle() result to appBarTitle variable?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I didn't put the init. I will modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign appBarTitle variable correctly. Try belowing code:

```
class _SearchView extends State<SearchView> {

final TextEditingController _filterController = new TextEditingController();

TextField buildAppBarTitle(BuildContext context) {
    return new TextField(
        controller: _filterController,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: AppLocalization.of(context).search
        )
    );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: buildAppBarTitle(context),),
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this creates a stack overflow

Comment: `return appBarTitle = new TextField..` There is a syntax error here. It should be like `return new TextField..`

Comment: No, also like this there will be a stack overflow. It just calls hundred of times  AppLocalization.of(context).search

Comment: It's like more than just this class. I need more information about the problem. For now, you can check this; 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Answer (score 0):

In the end I discovered that was not this chunk of code the real problem, but how I declared the String in the locale file:

```
  String get search => Intl.message("Search", name: search);
```

I forgot to put "search" in the name parameter, so:

String get search => Intl.message("Search", name: ***"search"***);